# What is the possible line of reasoning/motivation that led to the present definition of radians?

Tags: angle, motivation

I know this might sound like a silly question at first. Let me elaborate.

What I mean by 'line of reasoning; here is what the person who defined radians the way they are defined thought to arrive at that definition for radians.

I know about some advantages of using radians. For example, it makes the calculation of arc lengths easier and when we enter the value of $\alpha$ in radians, then $\dfrac{d(\sin\alpha)}{d\alpha} = \cos\alpha$ but when we enter the value of degrees, $\dfrac{d(\sin\alpha)}{d\alpha} = \dfrac{\pi}{180^o}\cos\alpha$ and the former seems simpler.

So, I'd like to know what steps of reasoning could have lead to the present definition of a radian i,e. the angle extended by an arc of length equal to the radius of a circle at the centre of that circle.

Thanks!

Comment: Radians are just a way to represent data - in this case, angles. I'm not sure what you are looking for here.

Comment: I'd say the arclength definition is very natural, no?  Unlike declaring that a right angle is $90$ which, really, is entirely arbitrary.  As far as I am aware, the only motivation for the usual angle measures is that $360$ is divisible by lots of small numbers.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radian#History

Comment: @lulu Actually I believe the $360$ comes from the Babylonian year with $12$ $30$-day months, though I've probably got the details wrong.

Comment: @saulspatz  Yeah, I have heard something like that too, but even so it's pretty random.

Comment: Babylonian year had $354$ days. The Wikipedia article https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radian has some useful information.

Comment: It seems Hipparchus was the one who introduced degrees.  The Babylonians didn't use them.

Comment: @lulu I read somewhere that the definition might have originated this way : Let the radius of a circle be $r$ and the length of an arc of it be $s$. Let the angle subtended by the arc at the centre be $\theta$. So, $s\propto\theta \wedge s\propto r\implies r\propto s\theta\implies s=k(r\theta)$, where $k$ is some constant. In radian measure, $k$ is defined as $1$. What you stated is basically a simpler restatement of this, right? Also, I'd love to know where I can find a detailed 'derivation' like the one I mentioned here because I'm a little confused about the dimensions of $k$, thanks!

Comment: $k$ is dimensionless. if you like, you can define radian measure as the ratio of the subtended arclength to the radius.  Often, one sticks to the unit circle so the radius is left off (you are just dividing by $1$).

Comment: @lulu Why would $k$ be dimensionless, though? On the left side, we are measuring the arc length, which is measured in length units whereas if we consider $k$ as dimensionless, then the units on the right hand side will be length times angle, right? So, shouldn't the dimension of $k$ be the reciprocal of that of an angle? Or, is the angle dimensionless?

Comment: $s$ and $r$ are lengths.  $k$ and $\theta$ have no dimensions.

Comment: @lulu Is that true by convention?

Comment: Well, you could say that.  I prefer to note that angle is unchanged if we double all the dimensions on the plane, hence it is dimensionless.

Comment: @lulu That's some nice intuitive way to think about it, thanks!